# Automating Login using python mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize, autologin

so this is my first time programming ever and I'm trying to automate logging into a website using python/mechanize. So this is my code:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# Want debugging messages?
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
br.set_debug_responses(True)


br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615  Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

br.add_password('http://newiso.accellion.net/w', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
br.open('http://newiso.accellion.net/w')


# Show the html title
print br.title()

# Show the response headers
print br.response().info()

# Show the available forms
for f in br.forms():
   print f

br.form["g_username"] = "USERNAME"
br.form["password"] = "PASSWORD"

import urllib
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener()
print opener.open('http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@newiso.accellion.net/').read()
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dancetrina/Documents/login.py", line 45, in <module>
br.form["g_username"] = "USERNAME"
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

does that mean that I can't use mechanize to type in the username/password? Or is there something I'm missing that would make it work? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Is there an actual login form, or is it using HTTP authorization headers?

Comment: @Blender yes there is an actual login form

Answer (score 1):

In the last (and *only* :-) ) `for` loop, you should write:

```
f.form["g_username"] = "USERNAME"
f.form["password"] = "PASSWORD"
```

Comment: uhhh but now I'm getting this?Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Users/dancetrina/Documents/login.py", line 44, in <module>
        f.form["g_username"] = "USERNAME"
       File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/mechanize/_form.py", line 2682, in __getattr__
         return getattr(HTMLForm, name)
     AttributeError: class HTMLForm has no attribute 'form'